How to play a MIDI file in a loop with AVMIDIPlayer?
I would like to play a MIDI file in a loop using AVMIDIPlayer.
I tried doing this using the completion handler of AVMIDIPlayer.play()  (see code below). This however results in a small delay between loops and clipping of the audio between loops. I would be very happy with suggestions on how to avoid both the delay and clipping.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var midiPlayer = MIDIPlayer()
       
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                midiPlayer.isLooping = true
                midiPlayer.playMIDI()
            }) {
                Text("play MIDI")
            }
            Button(action: {
                midiPlayer.stopMIDI()
            }) {
                Text("stop MIDI")
            }
        }
    }
}

class MIDIPlayer: ObservableObject {
    var midiPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?
    var isLooping: Bool = true
       
    init() {
        loadMIDI()
    }
    
    func loadMIDI() {
        guard let midiFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cdec", withExtension: "mid") else {
            print("no midi file")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let soundBankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Nokia", withExtension: "sf2")
            
            midiPlayer = try AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: midiFileURL, soundBankURL: soundBankURL)
            midiPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Error loading MIDI file: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func playMIDI() {
        midiPlayer?.play {
            if self.isLooping {
                self.midiPlayer?.currentPosition = 0
                self.playMIDI()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopMIDI() {
        isLooping = false
        midiPlayer?.stop()
        midiPlayer?.currentPosition = 0
    }
}


